# OSStatus-43 Error

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am keeping recorded audio file reference in SQLite database. When I am fetching the data and trying to play I find the error OSStatus-43. If there is any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into an error -43 when trying to play a remote mp3 file over http. I got around this by using an `AVPlayer` instead of an `AVAudioPlayer`.

Answer (score 1):

That's `fnfErr` for "file not found." Without more specific info or code, I can't help you more. Probably Core Audio is trying to open a file with your audio and the path is wrong.